# Why are function parameters immutable in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

The [Swift 3 documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) states that parameters are immutable:

> Function parameters are constants by default.

It also [states that](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html) value types are copied when passed into functions:

> Strings, arrays, and dictionaries are copied when they are passed to a function or method.

So, why are parameters **both** immutable and copied? If the argument is a constant, then we don't need a copy of its value in the function's scope. If the argument is copied, then the original variable passed in cannot be modified in the function (for value types).

Moreover, immutability seems inconvenient as we can't make local changes to an argument without first explicitly copying it (once again) to a local variable.

Am I reading the documentation incorrectly? Is there a good reason why this is the case?

Comment: FYI - Strings, arrays, and dictionaries are copied because they are `struct` types (value type), not `class` types (reference type). The copy is done for any assignment, not just as parameters.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense for assignment, but my confusion is at why value types are both copied and made immutable as parameters (one or the other should be enough?).

Comment: Think of all parameters as `let`.

Comment: Okay, but why use `let` and copy it?

Comment: This is a very good explanation: https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E21-structs-and-mutation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The motivation for this is described here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md

**tl;dr**: it avoids confusion with the `inout` keyword.